# How to control my itemized overlay on map?

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I  want to add new   place when i long touch on the map, I can  but  the  problem is  when  i add the  overlay i can't  move the map.  The  code is below.

```
public class CustomPinPointOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private GeoPoint newMarkerLocation;

    public CustomPinPointOverlay(GeoPoint newMarkerLocation,
            Drawable defaultMarker) {

        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        this.newMarkerLocation = newMarkerLocation;
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return new OverlayItem(this.newMarkerLocation, null, null);
    }

    public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
            boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

this is  my  overlay class which extends itemizedoverlay. other part of code is ;

```
public PMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

  setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        int x, y;
        long start, stop;


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                start = e.getEventTime();
                x = (int) e.getX();
                y = (int) e.getY();

                touchedPoint = map.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);
            }
            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                stop = e.getEventTime();

            }

            if (stop - start > 1000) {

                setEnabled(true);
                Drawable myMarker = getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.yeni_pin);
                getOverlays().add(
                        new CustomPinPointOverlay(touchedPoint, myMarker));


                return false;
            }


            return true;
        }


    });

}
```

what's wrong with this  code?

Comment: I  think the  problem is my setOnTouchListener.In my opinion setontouch listener is listening  my  touch until i click long. i mean  if i don't do  anything except stop-start>1000 my  setontouchlistener keeps  going on listening until i do  that. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is assuming that your PMapView extends MapView.

If the above statement is true you should try calling your superclass's `onTouchEvent` unless you handle it. For example (this is your code modified but I have not tested it)

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

        boolean retValue = true;
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            start = e.getEventTime();
            x = (int) e.getX();
            y = (int) e.getY();

            touchedPoint = map.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);
        }
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            stop = e.getEventTime();

        }

        if (stop - start > 1000) {

            setEnabled(true);
            Drawable myMarker = getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.yeni_pin);
            getOverlays().add(
                    new CustomPinPointOverlay(touchedPoint, myMarker));


            retValue = false;
        }

        if(!retValue)
            super.onTouchEvent(e);
        return retValue;
    }
```

The above code will pass on actions that are not captured (your long click is captured) back to the parent so it can handle things like moving the map.  This code has not been tested so it may give weird results. You may want to remove the `if(!retValue)` and just always call `super.onTouchEvent(e)`.